# Am I returning a string type correctly?

Tags: java

I am wondering if I am correctly using the return type? My assignment has specifically requested the method to be of string type so must return something.

```
public static String displaySystemProperties() {

      Properties pros = System.getProperties();
      pros.get(System.out);

      System.out.println();
      System.out.println("*****System Properties*****");

      System.out.println("Operating System Architecture: " + System.getProperty("os.arch"));
      System.out.println("Operating System Name: " + System.getProperty("os.name"));
      System.out.println("Operating System Version: " + System.getProperty("os.version"));
      System.out.println("User Account Name: " + System.getProperty("user.name"));
      System.out.println("Java Version: " + System.getProperty("java.version"));
      System.out.println();

      if(System.getProperty("os.name").equals("Windows 10")) 
      {
          System.out.println("Thumbs up! Your operating system is Windows 10");
      }
      else if(System.getProperty("os.name").equals("Linux")) 
      {
          System.out.println("Thumbs down! Your operating system is Linux");
      } 

      else 
      {
          System.out.println("Your choice of operating system is ok");
      }

        return System.getProperty("os.arch")+ System.getProperty("os.name")+ System.getProperty("os.version")+ System.getProperty("user.name")+ System.getProperty("java.version");


  }
```

Having tried the below code this is the error that I get [Launch error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AAuvv.png)

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: The eclipse prompt tells you that there is a compilation error.

Comment: yes but it doesn't say what.

Answer (score 1):

That is how you would do it yes - if a property doesn't exist then it returns the string "null", which is fine in terms of errors - but may not be an ideal thing for you to display to a user if they are do not know what null means.

Also, your return will be mixed together. try for example

`system.getproperty('property')+" "+system.getproperty2()`...

Comment: It seems to compile okay without any null pointer exceptions. But how would I check?

Comment: It will compile fine but may throw an error during runtime if the value is null, you can check with a simple if
```String result = "";
if(System.getProperty("os.arch")!=null){
result += System.getProperty("os.arch");
}
return result;```
as a basic example

Comment: No, it won't throw any `NullPointerException` at runtime. If a property won't be found, it will return the string, `null` for that e.g. `return System.getProperty("abc")+ System.getProperty("os.name")+ System.getProperty("os.version")+ System.getProperty("user.name")+ System.getProperty("java.version");` will return `null...` if there is no property set for the variable `abc`. The `...` if for the remaining part of the string.

Comment: @GiselleTadman he is correct, he is saying that if it doesn't exist it will return the word null rather than actual null, so it would be like "null null null null" - java isn't a language I often use so this was my mistake

Comment: thanks @ArvindKumarAvinash I have updated my answer

Comment: @JasonStephenson - You are most welcome.

Comment: Now it doesn't bring up errors. But has a launch error.

Comment: what is the error @GiselleTadman and what is your updated code

Comment: My code is still the same. I haven't changed anything because I'm not sure what to do still. I get the general launch error

Comment: @GiselleTadman I don't know what you mean by general launch error, do you have a stacktrace?

Comment: No. And I can't upload images... it's the dialogue box that tells you when there is an error in compiling?I have included it in my question.

Comment: @GiselleTadman - As per [SRP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-responsibility_principle), a method/module should perform only one thing. Your method, `displayDetails` is doing two things: (1) Printing the required properties (2) Returning the string having the required properties. I suggest you change it to do only one of these. If you want it to do the first one, you should change the return type to `void`. If you want  it to do the second one, remove all print statements from it and then replace `s1.displayDetails()` with `System.out.println(s1.displayDetails())`.

Answer (score 1):

There is no compilation problem in your code but certainly, it is not returning what you need. You need to append all the strings to a form the desired string and then return the same. Do it as follows:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Test
        System.out.println(getSystemProperties());
    }

    public static String getSystemProperties() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append("*****System Properties*****")
        .append("\n")
        .append("Operating System Architecture: ")
        .append(System.getProperty("os.arch"))
        .append("\n")
        .append("Operating System Name: ")
        .append(System.getProperty("os.name"))
        .append("\n")
        .append("Operating System Version: ")
        .append(System.getProperty("os.version"))
        .append("\n")
        .append("User Account Name: ")
        .append(System.getProperty("user.name"))
        .append("\n")
        .append("Java Version: ")
        .append(System.getProperty("java.version"))
        .append("\n");

        if (System.getProperty("os.name").equals("Windows 10")) {
            sb.append("Thumbs up! Your operating system is Windows 10")
            .append("\n");
        } else if (System.getProperty("os.name").equals("Linux")) {
            sb.append("Thumbs down! Your operating system is Linux")
            .append("\n");
        }

        else {
            sb.append("Your choice of operating system is ok");
        }

        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
*****System Properties*****
Operating System Architecture: x86_64
Operating System Name: Mac OS X
Operating System Version: 10.14.6
User Account Name: arvind.avinash
Java Version: 11.0.3
Your choice of operating system is ok
```